# In a hypothetical 'Snuff film' gameshow with roles, skills, a mastermind, etc., what would good win conditions be?

Tags: society, technology, politics, super-powers

Basically, this is a hypothetical gameshow, which stemmed from a gameshow with participants being able to enter if given a death sentence, in order to alleviate their sentence, lessen it, etc.

There are fifteen participants, one of whom has control of the game, and is the architect.

Participants are allowed to kill each other, however they don't have to. For the most part. There are two exceptions, for people who have failed the game four times.

The win conditions vary from role to role.

The Leader is able to make major decisions on behalf of the other players. They win if every other surviving (key word here: surviving) player (aside from Betrayer and Hunter) has fulfilled their win condition.

The Actor is able to use the abilities of any dead person they touch, without taking on their win condition. They win if they get a large number of the in-game currency.

You get the idea.

But I can't think of win conditions for certain roles.

Can anyone think of win conditions for these next roles?

Ideally, I don't want to add too many elements to the game, but I might be willing to if it fits with the theme of the role.

Joker: Can switch where certain doors lead to, and has various prank-themed mini-powers.

Messenger: Can send an anonymous message to anyone they desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messenger and Joker should both have to cause a death without killing the person. Both of their skills are very useful to the group, which means there is no reason to kill them unless they have something to gain from betraying the group.

The Messenger is a great player, if you can trust him to actually send the message you want him to send. If he doesn't, he'll get you killed, one way or another. The group has to weigh the benefits of keeping the messenger alive, if they find out who he is. That also means that the Messenger has two ways to play the game: he can tell the group who he is and hope they'll think he's worth keeping on, or he can hide himself and try to lure someone astray.

Likewise, the Joker has a nifty skill set, if he's on your team. I imagine that the Joker could pull off all kinds of magic tricks for his allies, but he could also trap and trick his enemies. Like the Messenger, he has two ways to play the game: he can tell the group or he can make his own way.

Now, seeing as you have a Betrayer already lined up, I don't know what the rules are about other members betraying, but both the Messenger and the Joker are in prime positions to betray. In addition, setting these conditions for the Joker and the Messenger guarantees you two deaths, as either they will both kill one person, or the others will kill them both. If you pick the right person to be the Joker, you might get many more that the required three deaths.

Comment: The reason three deaths are guaranteed, is because the Betrayer kills someone at the start of the game, and both the Betrayer and the Killer need to kill to win, and die if they don't.

Comment: The win conditions cannot involve killing, because all the core 12 need to be able to win together.

Answer (score 5):

The game Town of Salem is very similar to your idea.

[Wiki link to the roles in that game](http://town-of-salem.wikia.com/wiki/Roles)

There are 3 main factions in this game, the Town, The Mafia, and Neutral. Generally, Only one of the 2 main factions (Town and Mafia) can win, while the Neutral have special win conditions. A lot of their Roles can be quite useful as general ideas, though there are too many to list out here, some good ones might be :

TOWN:

Investigator: Finds out clues about who others are

Sheriff: Can watch people

Spy: Spies on the Mafia.

Mafia:

Godfather: Can kill people

Consigliere (Consig): Finds out peoples roles

Consort: Distracts others, Preventing them from doing their roles.

Neutral:

Executioner: Trick Town to lynch an assigned target

Serial Killer: Can kill people

Edit: Your game is specifically 15 individuals, split 12 and 3, and 3 minimum deaths it seems. You would need at minimum 2 win conditions, One for each of these "factions". Even if the 12 have the same win condition, killing each other is completely possible if any of them have any reason to lie about their roles, and no way to prove someone is telling the truth. If the Architect has to write out their order in private, then someone could pretend to be the architect in public, while the real one just copies what they say to make them look the part. If the 12's goal is to have the 3 die, then they need to identify the 3, but the 3 would likely do everything in their power to hide the fact they are one of the 3. When 2 people claim to be a role only one person can have, you cant even be sure both are lying and a third person is the real one, hiding it for some other reason.

As well, Individuals an have their own win conditions. you seem to want that, but truthfully its not nessecary. The Jestor is the prime example though of how to use it. They win by getting targeted by the group as a whole to die. Meaning if the main goal of the 12 is to kill the 3, but one of the 12 is a Jestor, they might try to make you think they are one of the 3. By doing so, they get rescued and win, leaving 14 people, each now more likely to die because of it. If done to obviously however, they might just get secretly murdered and so not get rescued, helping the 3 win. The mere idea that someone is a Jestor means you cant truly rely on information not gathered by yourself, which is bound to cause deaths of the 12 due to simple mistrust. So long as the win condition for the 12 does not require 12 people, then confusion about who the 3 are will lead to deaths. If some of the individual win conditions include killing certain other individuals, possibly of the 12.

Comment: I'm already aware of Town of Salem. In this hypothetical scenario, there are 3 guaranteed deaths, with two basic factions, that do not necessarily have to work together. One faction is comprised of 12 roles, who can choose to kill each other if they want to, but don't have to. The other is comprised of 3 roles, all of whom are outsiders to the core 12, and all of whom need deaths to ensure their survival. In order for the 12 to be able to safely kill each other, yet also win together, I need to make it so they each win in a different circumstance.

Comment: @Piomicron Or you could have it so that the win conditions are the same, the killing of certain individuals, but its hard to determine who they are, and perhaps others on the same faction can interfere with each other, meaning killing them might benefit the faction as a whole. If say someone who can lock another person up locks up your factions investigator, thinking they are the Consigliere, Killing them might be worth it to free the individual. Confusion is your friend here. might need to add that